What kind of marriages was the Rambam thinking of?
Mishnah Torah, Hilchot Biah, 12:1 speaks of “derech ishut” and 12:14 speaks of “derech chatnut.” How does the halacha understand these terms? Sources appreciated.
Note: The translation by Rabbi Eliyahu Touger identifies them as (rabinically approved?) marriages.

I think they are both referring to the same thing, especially since the first one brings a verses that also refers to "חתנות", that is, "לֹא תִתְחַתֵּן בָּם". They both mean, marry rather than just having sexual relations. As the Rambam makes clear, the prohibitions here are different depending on whether the relationship is casual or permanent.


As to how exactly one would violate these things, given that in Jewish law no such permanent relationship can actually exist, I don't have a source but I assume that "moving in together on a long-term basis" would qualify. That's kinda how we consider the בעלות of regular non-Jews getting married.



MichoeIR. Thanks for your comment. These seem to be marriages between  Jews and non-Jews without kiddushin, but with chuppah (consummation.)


Yes, but not just consummation/relations. The same is true for the laws of non-Jews, for example the prohibition against adultery in the Seven Noachide commandments. They are not considered married just because they had relations.

As a rule, Judaism does not define terms, as it allows for such a large degree of freedom in interpretations and legal rulings. Following the Talmudic tradition, Ramabm is known for not being exact with terms, for example, while dedicating a separate book to defining the 613 Mitzvos he extensively uses that term for other "desirable behaviors". This is why the translation is the same.
